# SVG/React Syntax Error only on Reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, webpack

I am trying to load an SVG in my React Component.

I require the SVG in the following way:

```
<img src={require('../../images/logo.svg')}/>
```

Here is my webpack loader:

```
{
     test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)([\?]?.*)$/,
     loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]'
},
```

Now if I start my webpack server and then add the `<img>` code above, everything works perfectly. However, when I refresh, I get the following error:

```
{ [SyntaxError: <absolute path>/nm-logo.svg: Unexpected token (1:1)]
  pos: 1,
  loc: Position { line: 1, column: 1 },
  _babel: true,
  codeFrame: '\u001b[0m> ...}
```

Also, If I navigate to `http://localhost:9000/static/logo.svg` even with the error the logo appears like it should.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue, would love to know what's going on here

Comment: Did you end up figuring out more? Googling the error only brings up this result.